TypeScript project automatically adds itself as a local dependency when running or building with Next.js or Express
I'm working on a TypeScript project using Next.js, and I've encountered an issue where the project automatically adds itself as a local dependency in the package.json file. Below is an example of my package.json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev --port 3000",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // other dependencies
    "next": "^13.4.13",
    "my-project": "file:" // This part gets added automatically
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // dev dependencies
  }
}

The problem is that the project name "my-project" is being added as a local dependency ("my-project": "file:"). I haven't manually added this entry, and I'm not sure why it's happening. This issue seems to occur whenever I run or build the project.
This also happens with Nodejs and Express project.
I've tried running npm unlink ozura, which temporarily removes the self-referencing dependency, but it gets added back again. I also tried clearing the cache with npm cache clean --force, deleting node_modules, and removing package-lock.json, followed by a fresh install. Unfortunately, the issue persists.
Has anyone encountered this issue before? What might be causing this behaviour, and how can I stop the project from automatically adding itself as a dependency?

if you are using VS code and installed the extension Red Hat Dependency Analytics disable it for now , for my case it was the problem with their last version (V 0.9.5 )

Just had this exact same issue with this same VSCode instance.

*Extension (not instance)

Thanks dude, I uninstalled VS Code itself and reinstall the dependencies that I know I need. IDK how or when the Red Hat Dependency Analytics was installed as I don't remember installing it. Anyhow thanks, as now I know not to install that again.
